# Padding in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to generate 10 item array of 3 random characters.  How come I'm getting extra padding in this array?  (["undefineddhe", "undefinedjih", "undefinedeih", "undefinedfjj", "undefinedhdb", "undefinedidc", "undefinedhbk", "undefinedggd", "undefinedfeg", "undefinedcgk"])

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
(function rand(alpha){
   var sequence = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){(function(i){
       for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){(function(j){
         sequence[i] += alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1];
       })(j)}
   })(i)}
return sequence;
})(arr);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAkVw/

Answer (score 3):

Because you are saying `sequence[i] += ...`.

By default `sequence[i]` is `undefined`.

```
var a;
a += "hello";
console.log(a); // "undefinedhello"

var b = "";
b += "hello";
console.log(b); // "hello"
```

You can fix this:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
(function rand(alpha){
   var sequence = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){(function(i){
       sequence[i] = "";
       for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){(function(j){
         sequence[i] += alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1];
       })(j)}
   })(i)}
return sequence;
})(arr);
```

---

Btw. you don't need to all the closures because your script is running sync:

```
 var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
(function rand(alpha) {
   var sequence = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       sequence[i] = "";
       for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
         sequence[i] += alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1];
       }
   }
   return sequence;
})(arr);
```

or I think i would prefere to make a named function:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

var a = sequence(arr);

function sequence(alpha) {
   var sequence = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       sequence[i] = "";
       for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
         sequence[i] += alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1];
       }
   }
   return sequence;
};
```

Comment: @SLB If you find a solution to your answer to should mark the answer as the correct by pressing the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting "extra padding", JS converts `undefined` to string, since `sequence[i]` does not exist. So you're appending a random 3-letter word to `'undefined'` string.

Just add `sequence[i] = '';` within the first loop, like this:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
(function rand(alpha){
   var sequence = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){(function(i){
       sequence[i] = '';
       for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){(function(j){
         sequence[i] += alpha[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1];
       })(j)}
   })(i)}
return sequence;
})(arr);
```